# Loss function not able to capture the maxima of probability distribution

Tags: neural-networks, pytorch, mean-squared-error

I am trying to predict noise (random gaussian) with the help of a neural network. I am implementing a L2 loss (torch.nn.function.mse_loss) for computing the loss function between the prediction distribution and input distribution (random gaussian). Any suggestions on what I may do to correct this?

**1. For epoch 1 : Train loss 1.0933226346969604**

[image]

**2. For epoch 200 : Train loss 1.000555157661438**

[image]

**3. For epoch 400 : Train loss: 1.174836277961731**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaussian noise is usually 0-mean, meaning that *it cancels out* on average especially with a squared loss (e.g. MSE): so your approach won't work.

I think that you should instead *predict the mean and variance* of such noise distribution: in such a way you could handle noises that are not 0-centered too!

In practice, I guess you can get inspiration from variational autoencoders. I mean, you set-up a neural net to predict the mean and log-variance. Then the loss function will be the KL divergence between the predicted Gaussian distribution (the one parametrized by mean and `exp(log_var)`) and the Gaussian prior, which corresponds to the distribution that describes the noise: $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, in your case.

In principle, with such approach you can learn also non-Gaussian noise distributions.